# aspx.cs class that extend a .cs : why I can't get this value by the constructor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I Have this code :

MainPage.cs

```
public class MainPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string myVar = "";

    public MainPage()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        myVar = "Hello";
        HttpContext.Current.Items["myVar"] = myVar;
        base.OnPreInit(e);
    }
}

public class iUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected string myVar;

    public iUserControl()
    {
        myVar = (string)HttpContext.Current.Items["myVar"];
    }
}
```

Example.aspx

```
<%@ Register src="../context/master/Exz.ascx" tagname="Exz" tagprefix="uc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <uc1:Exz ID="Exz1" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Example.aspx.cs

```
public partial class interne_Example : MainPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("First : " + myVar + "<br />");
    }
}
```

Exz.ascx.cs

```
public partial class context_master_Exz : iUserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("Second : " + myVar + "<br />");
    }
}
```

I aspect this behaviour :

- I call `example.aspx`;
- on `OnPreInit()` it store in the `HttpContext` the value of `myVar`;
- after, I print it First on Example.aspx.cs (and it works);
- including `Exz.ascx` from `Example.aspx`, it should also print the value for the second time by `Exz.ascx.cs` Response.Write.  **But It print an empty value**!!!!

Why this? I see that I can resolve this problem editing the `iUserControl` class as :

```
public class iUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected string myVar;

    public iUserControl()
    {           
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        myVar = (string)HttpContext.Current.Items["myVar"];
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }       
}
```

but I really don't know why, with OnLoad, it works. Can you help me to resolve this trouble?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

This is a page/control lifecycle question. In order of when they fire:

MainPage.MainPage()

iUserControl.iUserControl()

MainPage.OnPreInit()

MainPage.OnLoad()

iUserControl.OnLoad()

Comment: Oh...it's a lifecycle problem. I think I'll learn some more about it. I also thought that MainPage.MainPage() was the last method (constructor) to be called... damn :)

Answer (score 2):

Because the constructor of iUserControl will be executed before OnPreInit of MainPage, but the OnLoad will be executed after